# Force my web application to be 67% for all large desktop resolution (media query)

Tags: html, css

Here's what I mean: If you view my web application (admin website) built with Boostrap 4, it looks great at 67% (zooming out using Mac CMD -) but at 100% (normal resolution) it looks too big.

How would I go about resolving that? Would you change the actual HTML/CSS or is it possible to force the users browser to view (viewport?) the screen at 67%?

Thanks.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Also, since "looks great" is in the eye of the beholder, different visitors to your webpage may have different ideas about at which zoom factor the page looks best.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something similar to the CSS below. This example will change the viewport height and with to 67% when the screen width is below 500px. I would suggest reading up on the [@media](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) rule and [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp).

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    @viewport {
        width: 67%; 
        height: 67%;
    }
 }
```

If you can give more information on what you are aiming to achieve and provide your current code, i'm sure you will receive further help.